# Android : Why BroadcastReceiver crashing?

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have this Broadcast receiver registered

```
public class NotifyAlarmBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver{
    public Context context;
    public static final String NOTI = "android.intent.action.MAIN";
// actually i want NOTI = "com.sumit.timekeeper.NotifyAlarm"
// this too is not working
// help me here please

@Override
public void onReceive(Context _context, Intent intent) {
    context = _context;
    Uri data = intent.getData();
    String reason = intent.getStringExtra("alarm_reason");
    Intent intentalarm = new Intent(NOTI, data);

    intentalarm.putExtra("reason", reason);
    context.startActivity(intentalarm);
}
```

}

and the manifest

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".TimeKeeperStartActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".NotifyAlarm"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.sumit.timekeeper.NotifyAlarm">
            </action>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name=".NotifyAlarmBroadcast">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.sumit.timekeeper.NotifyAlarmBroadcast" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

but when the line reaches       context.startActivity(intentalarm);
the application crashes

may be it is where we pass first parameter to Intent, i'm not clear about
please help me.

Comment: You may have more information about the crash from LogCat (DDMS -> LogCat tab)

Comment: Hi ccheneson, Thanks for the response. LogCat shows crash at context.startActivity(intentalarm); . Also i tried AlerDialog that too when hits alertDialogObj.show() crashes...Normal Intent with NotifyAlarm.class param also crashes when hits context.startActivity(intentObj); ? I'm in pretty naive stage that i cannot even understand what is going on in the OS level.

Comment: The only thing that works fine there is Toast, it doesn't crash when it reaches toastObj.show()

Comment: What is the error that the logcat is giving at that line? is it a NullPointerException? should context.startActivity be _context.startActivity?

Comment: Put a Log.i message in your activity to see if it goes inside the onCreate

Comment: Donal , it's java.lang.RuntimeExcepton

Comment: ccheneson, it's not going inside onCreate

Comment: Log your Uri variable data to string to see what that actually is, do the same with intentalarm to make sure its not null or something invalid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add the [FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) flag in your intent.

```
intentalarm.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Comment: This too didn't work for me. I think I'm not understanding the real behavior of BroadCasting. I'm trying  to learn it after finding some nice tutorials. If you know any good blogs explaining BroadCasting in Android, please give me a link to it. Thanks again.